# Android KEYCODE_DPAD to swipe

Tags: java, android, touch

I'm trying to implement the [snake game example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/index.html) on the android development site, but my phone has no D-pad, only a touch screen. What's the easiest way to go about changing (or adding) the functionality to use swipes of the finger as you would use scrolling a webpage instead of the D-Pad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SelectFilterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* ... */

        // Gesture detection
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

See

[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent tutorial [here](http://www.eridem.net/android-tip-010-left-and-right-swipe-gesture-events) on listening for swipe gestures.